# Add property to each object in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to add a property to each object in the array:

```
var capitals = [{
    country: "What's the capital of Ecuador?",
    choices: ["Quito", "Caracas", "Panama", "Loja"],
    corAnswer: 0
}, {
    country: "What is the capital of China?",
    choices: ["Shanghai", "Beijing", "Ghangzou", "Hong Kong"],
    corAnswer: 0
}];
```

Should become:

```
var capitals = [{
        country: "What's the capital of Ecuador?",
        choices: ["Quito", "Caracas", "Panama", "Loja"],
        corAnswer: 0,
        global: true
    }, {
        country: "What is the capital of China?",
        choices: ["Shanghai", "Beijing", "Ghangzou", "Hong Kong"],
        corAnswer: 0,
        global: true
    }];
```

The array can contain multiple objects. What kind of function do I need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) at this context,

```
capitals.forEach(function(itm){
 itm.global = true;
});
```

If you are not familiar with the usage of `forEach`, then you can do the same job by using a for loop.

```
for(var i=0,len=capitals.length;i<len;i++){
  capitals[i].global = true;
}
```

Comment: i'd suggest to use `.map` to not mutate original array of objects

Comment: @VladimirStarkov That will create a clone unnecessarily. This context does not require `map`, I believe.

Comment: OP didnt say anything about context, using `map` provide you explicit data flow instead of implicit one with `forEach`

Comment: `const capital = [{}, …].map(i => { i.global = true; return i; })` thats it

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have to support legacy browsers, then you could use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't attempt to answer the question. A good answer would show how to use that function in the context of this question.